# Cause onClick of a ListView row to offer editing options

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, layout-inflater

I'd like to have the effect of clicking on a row in a ListView and offering buttons to do basic editing with what I'm displaying in said row.
Now I don't mean to change a textview into an editable-textview exactly, rather something that just offers buttons like "edit" and "delete" for example.  This could be done with a popup but I'm trying to avoid this, I want these action buttons to be replacing the displayed content of that row.

At first I figured it could just have two layouts for inflating into rows.  One "active" and one normal.  On click it would just return the different layout for the row clicked and have a marker to indicate which row was the currently selected one.   First ran into issues I didn't expect with the inflated views being recycled as a listview is scrolled up & down.  Fine, ok, so I made an extension of BaseAdapter so I could do my own thing with getView().  Well I managed to get it to correctly allow recycling of views (and not reusing the "active" one where it wasn't suppose to be) *however* I see no way to make it refresh / reload the alternate layout except when scrolling said row off screen and then back on.   Seems there's no way to force getView() to actually happen unless a row leaves the screen and comes back.

So it's a two headed question.  One is there a way to make a single row swap out inflated views while it's being displayed?  And two maybe my method of doing this is a backwards way to accomplish what I want and is there a better way?

Thank you for your time!

```java
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    Boolean activeExists = false;
    if(convertView!=null && convertView.getTag()==(String) "active"){
        activeExists=true; }
    if (((position==activeFlag && activeExists==true) || (position!=activeFlag && activeExists==false)) && convertView!=null) {
        v = convertView;
    } else if(position==activeFlag && activeExists==false){
        v = inflater.inflate(rowlayoutActive, parent, false);
        v.setTag((String) "active");
    } else if (position!=activeFlag && activeExists==true) {
        v = inflater.inflate(rowlayout, parent, false);
    } else {
        v = inflater.inflate(rowlayout, parent, false);
    }
    bindView(position, v);
    return v;
}
```

(Outside of this getView I have `(int) activeFlag` to remember which one is the current "selected" and I have my own version of bindView which doesn't really differ that much from normal.  The boolean is a quick mark for already inflated views to keep the wrong one from going to the wrong row when recycled.)

Comment: Great question, and part of the answer might be that you consider the MVC model.  Strictly speaking, you should modify the underlying data to cause a change in the UI which suggests adding perhaps a boolean to your data "isEditing" or similar, set it with the click then calling notifyDataSetChanged.  In getView, you would test that boolean to use the appropriate layout.

Comment: Oh my goodness I feel so simpleton now. I only added `((myCustomBaseAdapterAsACast) myListVarName).notifyDataSetChanged()` and it immediately swapped the views onClick. I didn't have to edit anything about my custom adapter, apparently it works as I thought. I know I'd looked into notifyDataSetChanged & similar already but it didn't work before, I know why now. I did a cast to my adapter and it worked, but without I got nothing.
`myListVarName.notifyDataSetChanged()` Bullocks, you get nothing.
`((myCustomBaseAdapterAsACast) myListVarName).notifyDataSetChanged()`
Worked immediately.

Comment: I'd accept your comment as an answer but it wasn't posted as a response.  If you copy it over I'll accept it, regardless, thank you.  I think I was just stuck and a bit brain fried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, and part of the answer might be that you consider the MVC model. Strictly speaking, you should modify the underlying data to cause a change in the UI which suggests adding perhaps a boolean to your data "isEditing" or similar, set it with the click then calling notifyDataSetChanged. In getView, you would test that boolean to use the appropriate layout.